# C# App - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sqlite, input

I created an app in C# with SQLite Database. When I want to display data from database into a text box, I receive the error: "Input string was not in a correct format".

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connectionString = @"Data Source=.\mydb.db;Version =3Integrated Security=True";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Succes!");
                        SQLiteDataReader reader = null;
                        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select username from users where id='1'", conn);
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while(reader.Read())
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You connection tring is wrong

Comment: Maybe `Data Source=.\mydb.db;Version =3Integrated Security=True` should be `Data Source=.\mydb.db;Version =3; Integrated Security=True;`

Answer (score 0):

The code from [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) is like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
}
```

So maybe

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   textBox1.Text = reader[0];
}
```

That said I would be using the debugger to find out more about the element and what you should display.

Just putting it out there but I would be looking and c# MVC or C# Core with entity framework. It's much easier to interact with a database and something I would encourage.